# Kentico 10 - Blog Repeater and Transformations

Tags: kentico

On our development server I have:

1. Set up the blog
2. Created the first blog post
3. Populated & published the first blog post

However the actual first page of the blog is blank.  When I opened a ticket with Kentico they indicated that I might need to use a repeater and transformations for the preview details of each post and for viewing a specific post.

Can anyone point me to where I can learn how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you will need some basic Kentico Developer training first.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn is by looking at the existing examples. Kentico installation comes with a few site examples. I suggest you to install Corporate Site example, there you can look at  [andrew johnes blog](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/managing-website-content/blogs). It is under */Community/Blogs/Andrew Jones Blog*. It can be a good starting point.